# jsf difference in layout of same page when redirecting

Tags: css, redirect, jsf-2

I have a "strange" situation with `jsf` pages.

I have created a `CustomNotFoundPage.xhtml` where the site is redirecting to it when the user hit a non-existing page.

the output of this page is a little different from the output when I hit the `CustomNotFoundPage.xhtml`.

the difference occurs on the divs i have.
i use a template page with header left menu and main content.

the problem is that the header div is a bit "taller" and the left menu div is stuck with the main content div.

.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="./../Templates/mainTemplate.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


    <ui:define name="content">
        <h2>The Requested page not Found</h2>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

HeaderCSS

```
root { 
    display: block;
}

h1{
    color : #ffffff ;
    border-bottom-width: initial;
    border-bottom-style: initial;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.HeaderCenter{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

cssLayout

```
#top {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #036fab;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#bottom {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c2dfef;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    background-color: #ece3a5;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}

.center_content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding: 5px;
}

.left_content {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 180px;
}

.right_content {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px 170px 0px 170px;
}

#top a:link, #top a:visited {
  color: white;
  font-weight : bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#top a:link:hover, #top a:visited:hover  {
  color: black;
  font-weight : bold;
  text-decoration : underline;
}
```

default.css

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, "Verdana CE",  Arial, "Arial CE", "Lucida Grande CE", lucida, "Helvetica CE", sans-serif;
    color: #000000;  
    margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Arial, "Arial CE", "Lucida Grande CE", lucida, "Helvetica CE", sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AFAFAF; 
    font-size:  16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #D20005;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  color: #045491;
  font-weight : bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link:hover, a:visited:hover  {
  color: #045491;
  font-weight : bold;
  text-decoration : underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed it.

at the web.xml at the section

```
<error-page>  
     <error-code>404</error-code>  
     <location>/faces/Secured/TestNotFound.xhtml</location> 
</error-page>
```

i added the paramter "?faces-redirect=true" and now works as it should be. I cant understand exaclty the problem but from the firebug of Firefox i notice that without the previous parameter the page was enclosing a full html code of the notfoundpage.xhtml